# mysql : выборка из двух таблиц с count() во второй

Tags: mysql

Смысл выборки состоит в том,чтобы из одной таблицы выудить количество уникальных позиций, из второй - количество позиций,соответствующих выборке из первой таблицы.
Вот такой запрос работает корректно:

```
SELECT t1.*,COUNT(t2.*) as cnt FROM t1 JOIN LEFT t2 ON t1.field=t2.field GROUP BY t1.field
```

Вопрос : является ли такой запрос оптимальным?
Не будет ли при каждой итерации в правой таблице подсчитываться общее количество позиций соответствующие условию ,а  потом выполнятся группировка ? То есть не будет ли излишней работы ?
Вроде бы MYSQL отрабатывает быстро, но и позиций мало в таблице.

Comment: *Вопрос : является ли такой запрос оптимальным?* Да. Желательно наличие индексов по полям связывания. *Не будет ли при каждой итерации ...* Не будет никаких итераций.

Comment: Спасибо . Тогда еще один подвопрос : можно ли кроме общего числа позиций COUNT(t2.*) внести еще один столбец для вывода где будет выводится общее количество позиций ,но только с определенным параметром , то есть плюс COUNT(t2.*) , но где, например, field2=1 - все это в одном запросе. Если можно то так это осуществить?

Comment: Нашел ответ но функция не работает + COUNT(IF(filed2=NULL,1,NULL))

Comment: Все вопрос снять - забыл использовать ISNULL

Comment: В MySQL это делается проще. Используется то, что BOOLEAN не существует, а TRUE и FALSE, получаемые при проверке условий, являются алиасами 1 и 0 соответственно. Т.е. `SELECT t1.*,COUNT(t2.*) as cnt, SUM(field2=1) AS cnt1 FROM t1 JOIN LEFT t2 ON t1.field=t2.field GROUP BY t1.field`